# Translation of formula field code into SQL

Tags: formula, formula-field, sql, data, data-extract

I am building a DWH and am currently working on our Salesforce data extractions. In order to improve data quality I would like to extract the formulas from custom fields and [translate them into SQL](https://fivetran.com/docs/applications/salesforce/formula) like Fivetran does with their [salesforce connector](https://fivetran.com/docs/applications/salesforce).

Extracting the formula code is easy using SFDC metadata API. For the translating however, I have researched quite a bit and haven't found any utility or open source library that can dynamically translate the formulas into a SQL.

Does anyone know of a tool or library that could help me with the translation?